# How to get value between particular characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like `"abc('x','y','zzz')"` and I wish to get an array of strings containing "x", "y" and "zzz" (i.e. string between `'` (Single quote)) from it. I have to do this in javascript.

It would not be easy to do it using substring method. I wish to get a method which returns an array of the characters between `' (single quote)` from the passed string.

Comment: Is there a possibility that a single quote is escaped `'a\'bc'` ?

Comment: @HamZa: No, basically, the string is an event in javascript like, onchange="abc('x','y','zzz')"

Comment: _"the string is an event in javascript like ..."_ -- That suggests a deeper issue. XY problem? Why do you need to parse this exactly?

Comment: @elclanrs: It would be very difficult to explain it, too big a thing to explain here. I have explained the crux of what is needed :).

Comment: Without knowing the details, it just doesn't seem like the right approach. If my intuition is correct, you might be wasting your time. A description of the actual problem would improve your chance at getting insightful answers and not just quick regex fixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following :

```
var input = "abc('x','y','zzz')";
input = input.match(/\w+/g); // ["abc", "x", "y", "zzz"]
input = input ? input.slice(1) : []; // ["x", "y", "zzz"]
input = input.length > 1 
    ? input.slice(0, -1).join(', ') + ' and ' + input.pop()
    : input[0] || ''; 
// "x, y and zzz"
```

Wrapped inside functions :

```
// string -> array
function split(input) {
    input = input.match(/\w+/g);
    return input ? input.slice(1) : []; 
}

// array -> string
function format(input) {
    return input.length > 1 
        ? input.slice(0, -1).join(', ') + ' and ' + input.pop()
        : input[0] || ''; 
}

format(split("abc('x','y','zzz')")); // ["x", "y", "zzz"] -> "x, y and zzz"
format(split("abc('x','y')")); // ["x", "y"] -> "x and y"
format(split("abc()")); // [] -> ""
```

Similar question : [Make a list comma and "and"-separated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20438834/1636522).

Comment: Thanks, This worked. However, I didn't mean to say **and** as string. I wanted an array as an result. Changed it accordingly.

Comment: @Ankit Ask your questions with care, there are many guys like me working for you for free ;)

Comment: @Ankit That said, there is nothing to change, use `split` only.

Comment: Someone edited my question and added " (double quotes) in string, which made it look like I want it as string. However, I also wrote that i want and function which returns an array. I agree that there is nothing to be changed, the .slice(1) returns an array only. I didn't had to format it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Ankit That was me :) Indeed, your question mentionned a "string **x, y and zzz**" (singular) : http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20515812/revisions. Again, answers are for free, have mercy on the readers :)

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one such match, then:

```
"abc('x','y','zzz')".replace(/^[^\(]*\(|\).*$/g,'').match(/\w+/g); // ['x','y','zzz']
```

will do.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer a pure regex solution for this simple task instead of combining several string operations:

```
var input = "abc('x','y','zzz')";
input.match(/(?!')(\w+)(?=')/g) // ["x", "y", "zzz"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var str = "abc('x','y','zzz')";
// remove string before (
str = str.replace(str.slice(0, str.indexOf('(') + 1),'');
// remove the last )
str = str.substr(0,str.length - 1);
```

Now you have a string 'x','y','zzz'. If you want to make an array, just try this:

```
var strArray = str.split(',');
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hicurin/m4rnt/1/)